How to size a stratospheric hydrogen airship capable of supporting its own weight and 10kg of payload?
Is there a (simple) formula that tells me how to size a single lobe airship (volume, dimensions, max diameter) high-altitude platform and how much it should be inflated with hydrogen at sea level so that it climbs to 66,000 feet with 10kg of payload and stays there fully inflated? Do I account only for pressure change or are there other factors affecting this?

Study weather balloons.

One mol of helium has a mass of 4g, while a mol of nitrogen has a mass of 28g.  A mol has a volume of 22.4 litres at 0C, so a helium balloon has roughly 1g of buoyancy per litre of gas.  Once you’ve established a volume of gas is your balloon, the buoyancy doesn’t change with temperature or pressure provided that the air outside is at the same temperature and pressure as the helium inside.  For high altitude you’ll want your balloon to be full at your target altitude (you may be happy for it to burst at higher altitude or vent gas in a controlled manner) so at ground level it will be well under-inflated.  Helium tends to diffuse quickly through balloons but if your flight time is relatively short (a few hours) then you may not need to factor this in.
